# Objective C - fatal error

Tags: objective-c, button

I have a problem with my Xcode app, When I push a button, my app crashes.

Here is my button's action, I also declared variables, strings, etc... but it isn't in this code:

```
{
    NSLog(@" - Writing Data.plist Labels");
    NSString *error;
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects: compteur01, compteur02, compteur03, compteur04, compteur05, compteur06, nil]
                                                          forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"name1", @"name2", @"name3", @"name4", @"name5", @"name6", nil]];
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict
                                                                   format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                         errorDescription:&error];
    if(plistData) {
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error writeToFile:plistData:labels");
        [error release];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the crashlog look like? We need the message(s) and the call stack. Did you set an exceptions breakpoint?

Comment: This is certainly not an xcode app. xcode is your IDE. The app does not care whether you key in your code in xcode or notepad or whatever. Are you talking about iOS or OS-X or something different?

Comment: It's the part of my action wich has a bug.

Comment: Here's the error:*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (6)      FROM THE CRASHLOG

Comment: That's because your `compteur01` variable holds `nil`, so the array has no elements.

Comment: try `nslog(@"%@",compteur01);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently `compteur01` is nil.
Most likely the other compteur0x are nil too. But for this message at least the first one is nil.

Make sure that none of the objects added to the dictionary are nil. Use `NSNULL` instead if you need them to represent a nil/null value.